# Is network connection mandatory to install ubuntu ISO 20.04 LTS?

Tags: boot, upgrade, uefi

Is network connection mandatory to install ubuntu ISO 20.04 LTS?
We using the Desktop with efi.
If I disconnect network, Linux not booting after my installation.

If yes, What are the packages will try to download?
In ISO which file used to search the packages?

Comment: Seems like the real problem is "*Linux not booting after my installation*" but that description is too vague to offer useful advice.

Answer (score 4):

**No**,  *internet connection is not required*

Including Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS, Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS, and *flavors* of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with QA-testing performed without internet connection, with packages being installed limited to only those provided on the media.

Some install types do benefit from internet, such as re-installation of prior system with additional packages, does require internet connection so they can download the additional packages you had installed that are not included on the installation media (ie. an *Upgrade via re-install* used to repair your system to what was installed before hand, where you had packages not on installation media installed).  This example install type still works (*without internet*); **but** without internet any additional packages you had installed cannot be downloaded and thus won't be re-installed for you automatically.

Comment: "No internet connection is not required"...? I get what you intend to say through the markup, but it still is syntactically ambiguous without punctuation.